# Unsure how a block has ended up on a page

Tags: views, javascript

I've inherited an old drupal 6 site.  I'm 2 weeks into understanding the whole drupal system.

I have a page which loads a branch locator map.  It looks as if the map is a block created with openlayers and views.

The page where this block appears is in a 'Site Page' called 'branch locator'

If I go to 'Content Management > List' and then edit 'Branch locator'.  I am able to edit the text that appears on the page, but there is no setting to add or remove the map block.

I can't get my head around how the map block has ended up on the branch locator 'site page'.

I have trawled through the menu system to see how these 2 are linked but don't seem to be able to find any clues.

I looked into the template files as well to see if there was a custom template for the branch locator page and was then calling the block into it, so far I have not found anything.

How else could this have been achieved?

Comment: Have you checked the block configuration page?

Comment: Yes, I saw that the block was associated to a region.  But how does the block then only appear on the url 'branch-locator'?

Comment: The configure link for the block reveals no clues.  Everything is default/blank.  For example 'show on every page except those listed' is set and the text area below is blank.

Comment: @LucasScholten and does this region exist on another pages at all?

Comment: if it's a Views block, check out how it is created there.  If Views is using an argument that is relying upon it being displayed on a certain type of page, it could be returning nothing and thus nothing would show up on other kinds of pages.

Comment: @Molot yes the region is on all pages.

Comment: @jimajamma No, there are no arguments set in the view.  No path anywhere either.

Comment: then the next step would be to check and make sure what module is actually making the block.  you can check this easily in the html source and look at the various ids and classes associated with the block.  then look t that module and make sure in its block code it isn't doing something fancy before it gets to the Block and Views UIs.

Comment: What @Jimajamma says, but more solid method would be to check `{block}` table in database. After filtering it by theme and region you should be able to see your row easily, and check `module` column.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I checked the blocks table. The delta column says 'reseller_map_openlayers-block_1' which I believe is the machine name for the block.  The modules column shows 'views' the pages column shows 'node/2232' which is the page URL before it is rewritten.  Interesting, does this provide any clues?

Comment: Yes, that means the block will only display on node/2232. It also means that the fields on the block configuration page must not have been all empty as that comes from the "Pages" field in the visibility section.

Comment: @rooby I can confirm the fields are all definitely empty.

It's all very strange the 'branch-locator' page shows not only the text configured within the 'SitePage' area.  But that text is placed in a jquery show hide box (which is not coded from within the site page wysiwyg, even when I switch to plain view).  Then the block appears below.  This is what made me think there might be a custom template involved, but I can't seem to find it.